# IBM Worklight 6.1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'directUpdate' of undefined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight 6.1

I have developed an Android application with

```
connectOnStartup : true
```

and

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

When I try to execute the application on the device (4.1.2), when it starts I get the exception in log cat:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'directUpdate' of undefined
```

The application is a mix between the modules "Adapter-based authentication" and "Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications". Downloaded from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

If I do not set the set connectOnStartup to false it works.

Any idea?

Comment: I have edited the question. As I thought the issue was related to direct update and connectOnStartup I didn't thought the application content was needed.

Comment: Direct Update takes place on application startup and on return to foreground, so if you do not connect to the server (be it connectOnStartup, WL.Client.connect or otherwise), obviously a direct update won't happen and the issue will not manifest it self. Additionally, the API Level is of zero interest and the app implementation the most interesting part, which you did not mention at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You point me to the error, I thought there was nothing being executed before Direct Update but the java script code included in the main HTML page is executed before.

Then I realized that I didn't include the javascript file where the security challenge handler was implemented. Thas was the issue.

I have included the

```
<script src="js/SingleStepAuthRealmChallengeProcessor.js"></script>
```

in the .html and now it is working.

Thank you Idan.